# need help in wp_insert_post

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

this is very weird

i had this code working but then i needed some data from my database inorder to make sure that i am not creating the same post title again since if its not unique i want to generate another one.

i will post the code with what i added and made wp_insert_post stop.
however everywhere i searched i found that people should be including them:

```
<?php

define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
//local
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wordpress/wp-load.php' );
//live
//require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;

$subEmail = isset($_POST['subEmail']) ? $_POST['subEmail'] : null;

if($subEmail){

    //Check if $subEmail is in DB
    $dbEmails = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "_field_newsletteremail"' );
    foreach($dbEmails as $emailObj){
        if($subEmail === $emailObj->meta_value){
            echo "exists";
            die();
        }
    }
    //else create a coupon for him
    $couponCodeValue = $subEmail.time();
    $couponCodeValue = str_replace(' ', '', $couponCodeValue);
    $couponCodeValue = md5($couponCodeValue);

    //Get Existing Coupons we created
    $dbCoupons = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "shop_coupon" AND post_status = "publish"' );
    $x = 0;
    $y = 6;
    $couponCodeSixValue = substr($couponCodeValue, $x , $y);

    for($y; $y < strlen($couponCodeValue); $y++){
        //if code found generate new one, else just us the current
        if($dbCoupons[$i]->post_title === $couponCodeSixValue){
            $couponCodeSixValue = substr($couponCodeValue, ($x+1) , ($y+1));
        }
        $x++;
    }

    imagineme_create_coupon($couponCodeSixValue);

}


function imagineme_create_coupon( $couponCodeSixValue ){
    require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wordpress/wp-load.php' );        
    $coupon_code = $couponCodeSixValue; // Code
    $amount = '10'; // Amount
    $discount_type = 'fixed_cart'; // Type: fixed_cart, percent, fixed_product, percent_product

    $coupon = array(
        'post_title' => ''.$coupon_code,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
    );

    $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

    // Add meta
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'yes' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '1' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', '' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no' );

    echo $coupon_code;
}

?>
```

the function at the very bottom was working before i added :

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
//local
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wordpress/wp-load.php' );
//live
//require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
```

but without this i can not access the wpdb from this side script.

how can i make sure that all files for wp_insert_post are loaded and access it, since i am getting PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_insert_post()

Comment: Where do you place this code in which file?

Comment: this code is included in functions.php, and i am calling it using jQuery.post() from the index.php page

Comment: remove the `define( 'SHORTINIT', true );` and you don't need the `require_once` for the wp-load.php too its already loaded.

Comment: removing what you recommened @Shibi resulted in the following PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_results() on null

Comment: Oh I see you are using ajax but you are using it not in the wordpress way. Here you have examples https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: @Shibi maybe my ajax is not the way wordpress wants it, but i can print the vars i am posting and i can see the correct values, however ill check the codex like you sent, thanks